# Cannot view the downloaded file from webview android

Tags: android, webview, android-download-manager

I'm downloading file from webview using the below code,

```
if(!url.contains("sharepoint.com")) {
            if (url.endsWith(".pdf") || url.endsWith(".PDF") ||
                    url.endsWith(".xls") || url.endsWith(".xlsx") ||
                    url.endsWith(".XLSX") || url.endsWith(".XLS") ||
                    url.endsWith(".txt") || url.endsWith(".TXT") || url.endsWith(".doc") || url.endsWith(".DOC") ||
                    url.endsWith(".docx") || url.endsWith(".DOCX") || url.endsWith(".ppt") || url.endsWith(".PPT") ||
                    url.endsWith(".pptx") || url.endsWith(".PPTX") || url.endsWith(".rtf") || url.endsWith(".RTF") ||
                    url.endsWith(".csv") || url.endsWith(".CSV")) {
                mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
                    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                            String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                            long contentLength) {
                        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                                Uri.parse(url));
                        final String fileName= URLUtil.guessFileName(url,contentDisposition,mimetype);
                        Log.d("ss","fileName:"+fileName);
                        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
                        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName);
                        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                        dm.enqueue(request);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT); //This is important!
                        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE); //CATEGORY.OPENABLE
                        intent.setType("*/*");//any application,any extension
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

My url is "http://dev.citylaneapp.com/demo/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2017/02/InfoChantier.pdf"

But i could not view my downloaded file. Could you please suggest me to view the downloaded file?

Comment: You need to actually specify the type.  No application can open * / *, that would mean it could open any file that exists.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan I have tried that too. But its not working. Its showing "The file could not be accessed check the location or the network and try again".